# Capturing Video With SwiftUI and AVFoundation

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I've seen some examples of how to do video play back, but haven't found any examples of capturing video with SwiftUI. Does anyone know how to do this? Or does anyone know of any tutorials of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no specific "SwiftUI way" for capturing videos, unfortunately. You need to use `AVFoundation` and some `UIKit` wrapper code. [This tutorial](https://medium.com/@gaspard.rosay/create-a-camera-app-with-swiftui-60876fcb9118) gives a good starting point.